# Converting an AWS Lambda Function into a container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, containers, aws-fargate

I currently have a bunch of AWS Lambda functions and would like to spin them each up in containers (preferably Docker) to integrate with the current CICD pipeline. It's totally OK to have these containers spun up in an Amazon service such as Fargate -- the important thing is that it must be spun up in a container. The closest thing I've found is [this repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-container-image-converter) by Amazon that converts images into Lambdas, though this is the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Is this task possible, and if so what's the best way to go about it?

Comment: You need to add more information. First, what language are you using? Second, how are these containers being launched? Are you OK with "run and done" or do you expect multiple invocations of the handler function?

Comment: I'm using the python SDK, though the lambda functions could span multiple runtimes. "Run and done" is also all I'm looking for in the sense that I will only need to spin up one container, though the function itself within the container may be called multiple times (this requirement can potentially be relaxed).

Comment: Note that AWS SAM does something like this so that you can develop and debug Lambda functions locally (running in Docker).

Comment: I've looked into this very deeply, and it appears that I need a copy of the code used in the Lambda function. I unfortunately don't have access to this. I do have access to everything returned by the AWS Lambda GetFunction method.

Comment: If you can invoke `GetFunction` you should have access to the code: this operation returns a URL that can be used to retrieve the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this project which generates a Dockerfile and related artefacts from a lambda function: https://github.com/paololazzari/lambda2docker

Currently it supports Python only but will be working on adding support for other runtimes too.

Here's an example below.

---

Let's say we have deployed this Python function:

```py
# lambda_function.py
import requests
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Hello from lambda")
```

alongside a layer which contains `requests`.

To generate a Dockerfile:

```bash
$ lambda2docker --lambda-name my-lambda-function --region us-east-1 --flavor alpine
Dockerfile generated in output directory /tmp/tmpnl30z9us
```

Let's inspect what was generated:

```bash
$ tree /tmp/tmpnl30z9us
/tmp/tmpnl30z9us
├── Dockerfile
├── src
│   ├── lambda_function.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── wrapper_entrypoint.py

1 directory, 4 files

$ cat /tmp/tmpnl30z9us/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /data
ADD src src
ADD wrapper_entrypoint.py wrapper_entrypoint.py
RUN pip install -r src/requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

$ cat /tmp/tmpnl30z9us/src/requirements.txt
requests==2.30.0
```

This Dockerfile is buildable:

```bash
$ pushd /tmp/tmpnl30z9us
$ docker build -t my-lambda-container .
$ popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, a Lambda "function" is a Python script that listens for invocation events and invokes the actual handler function. This means that you can pretty easily invoke the function using the standard Python "script" code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = # this is the tricky part
    ctx  = # some dict that looks like what Lambda expects
    handler(args, ctx)
```

These two parameters are just dicts, so if you can populate them with something that looks right then you can wrap the entire thing in a container and deploy it to ECS or Batch, or your own Docker daemon.

The problem is how you populate them, and that depends on what your lambda functions do -- which you don't say -- and how they're invoked -- which you also don't say.

You could use command-line parameters. For example, if your lambda is intended to respond to an S3 `PutObject` operation, then all you really need is the bucket and key name. From that you can easily create a dummy [S3 invocation event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html), using fake values for all of the other fields.

If you invoke your Lambda in response to an SQS message it's even easier: your "main" handler enters a loop that polls SQS, and reformats the messages that it pulls off the queue.

Other event sources are going to be much harder. It may make sense (depending on why you're doing this) to use SQS for all invocations, and simply pass a fully-formed event message into the queue.